# Springboot 2.0 JUnit test @Tranactional rollback doesn't works

Tags: spring-boot, junit, hikaricp

I migrated some projects from `Springboot 1.5.10` to `2.0`.

`Springboot 2.0.3Release`, `JDK10`, `mysql`, `hikari-cp`

After this work, in `JUnit test`, all data in test cases remains at database. I think it doesn't works `@Tranactional` - `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

Here is part of `application.yml` and test class.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    database: mysql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Here is datasource.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatasourceJPAConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

Here is part of JUnit test class.

```
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@SpringBootTest
public class RepoTests {

     @Autowired
     private TestRepository testRepository;

     @Test
     public void saveTest() {
         var name = "test";
         var description = "test description"

         var item = TestDomain.builder()
             .name(name)
             .description(description)
             .build();

         testRepository.save(item);

         var optional = testRepository.findById(item.getId());

         assertTrue(optional.isPresent());
         assertEquals(optional.get().getDescription(), description);
         assertEquals(optional.get().getName(), name);
     }
}
```

after to run `saveTest` method, increase 1 row at database.

Answer (score 0):

Add datasource to test and [set auto commit](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource&method=setAutoCommit)  to false

```
 @Autowired
 private DataSource dataSource;
```

And inside test

```
  ((HikariDataSource)dataSource).setAutoCommit(false);
```

Comment: I fixed my code, then check `connection` configurations: autoCommit is `false`. but test codes still write values at database